# Delegate with generic type param - Compile error when generic type used as out param

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, delegates

I'm playing around with generics in a delegate, and I cant get it to compile when the generic type is used as an `out` parameter. Any ideas why? Maybe this is something that just cant be done, or maybe I've just missed something.

The problem:

```cs
// Doesnt compile when generic type used as out parameter ❌
// Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'TryParseDelegateTOut<Base>' 
delegate bool TryParseDelegateTOut<T>(string input, out T x) where T : Base;
Dictionary<string, TryParseDelegateTOut<Base>> parseMapTOut = new()
{
    { "a", A.TryParseTOut },
    { "b", B.TryParseTOut },
};
```

Full example:

```cs
interface IParser<T> where T : IParser<T>
{
    static abstract bool TryParseTOut(string input, out T thing);
    static abstract T ParseTReturn(string input, out int x);
}
class Base { }
class A : Base, IParser<A>
{
    public static bool TryParseTOut(string input, out A thing) { }
    public static A ParseTReturn(string input, out int x) { }
}
class B : Base, IParser<B>
{
    public static bool TryParseTOut(string input, out B thing) { }
    public static B ParseTReturn(string input, out int x) { }
}

// Everything seems OK when generic type used as return parameter ✅
delegate T TryParseDelegateTReturn<T>(string input, out int x) where T : Base;
Dictionary<string, TryParseDelegateTReturn<Base>> parseMapTReturn = new()
{
    { "a", A.ParseTReturn },
    { "b", B.ParseTReturn },
};

// ************************************************************
// ********** This is the problem I am talking about **********
// ************************************************************
// Doesnt compile when generic type used as out parameter ❌
delegate bool TryParseDelegateTOut<T>(string input, out T x) where T : Base;
Dictionary<string, TryParseDelegateTOut<Base>> parseMapTOut = new()
{
    { "a", A.TryParseTOut },
    { "b", B.TryParseTOut },
};
```

Error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'TryParseDelegateTOut'

However, it *does* compile if I replace the generic type in the dictionary, from `Base` to either of the derived classes, `A` or `B`, but obviously then I am tied to only that implementation of the base class. E.g.

```cs
delegate bool TryParseDelegateTOut<T>(string input, out T x) where T : Base;
Dictionary<string, TryParseDelegateTOut<A>> buildsWithTOut = new()
{
    { "a", A.TryParseTOut }, // Compiles OK ✅
    { "b", B.TryParseTOut }, // Doesnt compile, same error mentioned previously ❌
};
```

The reason this latter example doesnt work is fairly obvious - the dictionary is typed to the `A` class, so of course the specifying a value as `B.TryParseTOut` (which returns an instance of `B`) is clearly not going to work. Hence why I am initially trying to type the dictionary with the `Base` class.

Comment: "cannot convert from 'method group`" generally means you are trying to call a method/function and have forgotten the brackets.

Comment: @Neil in this case I'm not trying to call a method though, I'm just storing a reference to it.

Comment: Your dictionary value is of type TryParseDelegateTOut<A> but the 2nd initialiser is trying to initialise a TryParseDelegateTOut<B>.

Comment: @Neil Yes I know, which is why I'm trying to declare the dictionary using the *base* class at he bottom of the first snippet, `TryParseDelegateTOut<Base>>`.

Comment: <Base> appears to work for you and is the correct answer.  Is there another question about this?

Comment: @Neil Forgive me for being blunt, but I feel like either you havent really read the description, or maybe I havent made it clear enough? *"I cant get it to compile when the generic type is used as an out parameter."*, *"Doesnt compile when generic type used as out parameter"* when using `TryParseDelegateTOut<Base>>`. To be clear **<Base> does not work for me**

Comment: I can confirm your point. I don't know whether this by design or a bug. But in either case you could post an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues

Comment: Sorry @devklick, I read your question several times and still read it the opposite way you wrote it.  My bad.

Comment: Thanks both. I think I have realised why this doesnt work and have posted an answer below, if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

I've thought about this some more and I believe this error is completely valid. I've stripped away the generics and delegates from the example as these dont actually seem to be related to the problem. The problem is just combining inheritance with an output parameter.

Given the following:

```cs
private class Base { }
private class A : Base { }

private void OutA(out A a) => a = new A();
```

If I try to call this and specify the base class, I get an error:

```cs
OutA(out Base b1);
```

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'out MyProject.Base' to 'out MyProject.A'

Since output parameters are passed by reference, this code tries to pass an object of type `Base` into a function when type `A` is expected, which obviously cant be done since `Base` is not an `A`.

Although this is a different error to what's mentioned in the description, I believe this is the cause of the error in the description.